# Example in Sobolev Space

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

The function $\sqrt{x}$ is in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$, but can it be extended to $W^{1,1,}(-1,1)$? And in particular, is the function

$$f(x) = \chi_{[0,1]}\sqrt{x} $$

in $W^{1,1}(-1,1)$?  I'm trying to think of a way to choose a test function to show that it isn't, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{-x}$ for $x\in (-1,0)$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp You are saying that $f(x) = \chi_{(-1,0)}\sqrt{-x} + \chi_{(0,1)}\sqrt{x}$ will be in $W^{1,1}(-1,1)$?

Comment: You have $$\int_{0}^1\varphi'(x)\sqrt{x}\,dx = [\varphi(x)\sqrt x]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \varphi(x)\cdot\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}\,dx = -\int_0^1 \varphi(x)\cdot\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}\,dx.$$So, the generalized derivative of $\sqrt x$ is $1/(2\sqrt x)$, which is an element of $L^1(0,1)$. So, your function $f$ is indeed in $W^{1,1}(-1,1)$.